# Merge two columns maintaning missing values

Tags: r, merge, rowsum

I am trying to add two columns. My dataframe is like this one:

```
data <- data.frame(a = c(0,1,NA,0,NA,NA),
                   x = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0),
                   t = c(NA,2,NA,NA,2,0))
```

I want to add some of the columns like this:

```
yep  <- cbind.data.frame( data$a, data$x, rowSums(data[,c(1, 2)], na.rm = TRUE))
```

However the output looks like this:

```
> yep

      data$a  data$x   rowSums(data[,c(1, 2)], na.rm = TRUE)
  1        0      NA                                      0
  2        1      NA                                      1
  3       NA      NA                                      0
  4        0      NA                                      0
  5       NA       1                                      1
  6       NA       0                                      0
```

And I would like an oputput like this:

```
> yep

      data$a  data$x   rowSums(data[,c(1, 2)], na.rm = TRUE)
  1        0      NA                                      0
  2        1      NA                                      1
  3       NA      NA                                      NA
  4        0      NA                                      0
  5       NA       1                                      1
  6       NA       0                                      0
```

If the columns contain only NA values I want to leave the NA values.

How I could achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R (`ifelse`):

```
cbind(data$a,data$x,ifelse(is.na(data$a) & is.na(data$x),NA,rowSums(data[,1:2],na.rm = TRUE)))
```

If you are looking for the column name then replace `cbind` with `cbind.data.frame`

**Output:**

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   NA    0
[2,]    1   NA    1
[3,]   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    0   NA    0
[5,]   NA    1    1
[6,]   NA    0    0
```

Comment: All the answers are working. This one, also works when **a = x = 1**, this answer returns 2 instead 1. The answer of  markus works perfect for my example and if some one want to use the value from the first colum (in cases where are no missing data in both columns).

Answer (score 4):

Base R:

```
data <- data.frame("a" = c(0,1,NA,0,NA,NA),
                   "x" = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0),
                   "t" = c(NA,2,NA,NA,2,0)
)

yep <- cbind.data.frame( data$a, data$x, rs = rowSums(data[,c(1, 2)], na.rm = TRUE))
yep$rs[is.na(data$a) & is.na(data$x)] <- NA
yep
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try `dplyr::coalesce`

```
cbind.data.frame( data$a, data$x, dplyr::coalesce(data$a, data$x))
#  data$a data$x dplyr::coalesce(data$a, data$x)
#1      0     NA                               0
#2      1     NA                               1
#3     NA     NA                              NA
#4      0     NA                               0
#5     NA      1                               1
#6     NA      0                               0
```

Comment: This works fine with the example posted, but it doesn't get the `sum`. If there's a row with `a = x = 1` it will return `1` instead of `2`.

Comment: @AntoniosK You are right of course. Given the example data, I though `coalesce` will be "enough" for OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

base r ifelse

```
  data[['rowsum']]<-ifelse(is.na(data$a) & is.na(data$x),NA,ifelse(is.na(data$a),0,data$a)+ifelse(is.na(data$x),0,data$x))

     a  x  t rowsum
 1:  0 NA NA      0
 2:  1 NA  2      1
 3: NA NA NA     NA
 4:  0 NA NA      0
 5: NA  1  2      1
 6: NA  0  0      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R approach.

If all the values in the rows are `NA` then return `NA` or else return sum of the row ignoring `NA`'s.

```
#Select only the columns which we need
sub_df <- data[c("a", "x")]

sub_df$answer <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(sub_df)) == ncol(sub_df), NA, 
                    rowSums(sub_df, na.rm = TRUE))

sub_df
#   a  x answer
#1  0 NA      0
#2  1 NA      1
#3 NA NA     NA
#4  0 NA      0
#5 NA  1      1
#6 NA  0      0
```